# "A password reset request was sent..." System-level phishing?

Tags: security, apple-id, password, notifications

Over the course of the last two days I have received upwards of ten notifications alerting me that a password reset request was sent from some device. When I go to check my Apple ID email, I see no notifications to this effect. When I click the "Show" button, I am taken to System Preferences and given the opportunity to type in my administrator password to reset my Apple ID password. I have not done so.

The full message of the notification reads: "A password reset request was sent from a device at the location shown below."

I have a hard time believing this is a legitimate communication from Apple. The few others who have posted similar questions here and elsewhere have received unhelpful answers. Any idea what's going on here? Has my system been compromised somehow?

10.15.7 (19H2)

[image: "A password reset request..."]

Comment: I started getting these after resetting my apple password. It pops up every few hours. Its extremely annoying.

Answer (score 8):

I suggest changing your iCloud password and enabling 2-factor authentication if you haven't already.  But DO NOT click the notification to do this.  Go to [Apple's website](https://appleid.apple.com/) to do it.  (Also, don't trust anyone on the internet to give you a good link.  Check your URL bar to make sure you are at appleid.apple.com when you click even my link.)

Also, go to System Preferences -> Notifications and see what apps have notification access and restrict notification access to anything that looks suspicious.

Judging by the way the notification looks, it does not look legitimate as it does not have an app icon.  You can call Apple if you want to make sure, though.

Comment: It seems the notification is legitimate and occurs when "someone tries to reset your password via iforgot.apple.com and you have 2FA enabled" – see https://www.reddit.com/r/applehelp/comments/eh7enm/im_receiving_password_reset_request_messages_on/fchfger/

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same issue. I changed my Apple ID ( appleid.apple.com) and the notifications have gone away.

I contacted Apple Support about this. They said they were getting a lot of messages about this today (07.11.22) and shared with me the "[If you think your Apple ID has been compromised](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204145)" Apple support webpage.

FWIW- @Salocor's sage advice was best and spot on.

Best of luck.

Comment: Thx for sharing this but this reads like a comment rather than an answer. Pls do not post a comment as an answer and wait until you gain enough reputation points to write a comment in any case.

Comment: I got several of these today...
Good to know I'm not the only one, now I feel less worried.

Answer (score 1):

These messages **can** be legitimate. I'm on Big Sur and received the same notification. Shortly after I received a legitimate 2-FA code via SMS and a call with spoken code shortly thereafter. All these actions were not initiated by myself.

As a precaution I changed my password and tried went through the "forgot password"-steps myself to make sure this could be initiated without having my password. The good news is that these verification requests, texts and calls can be initiated by having only your e-mailaddress *and phonenumber*. So you can probably rest assured that your password is not compromised. Just to be sure, I'd recommend changing it anyways, as elaborately explained by user Salocor.